# What is imported when I use a struct from another module?

Tags: rust

I have the module **mod1.rs**:

```
pub struct Foo;

impl Foo {}

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}
```

In **file2.rs** I wrote `use mod1::Foo;`.

1. What do I actually have in **file2.rs**? Only `struct Foo`, `impl Foo`? What about `impl Drop for Foo`?
2. If I get all traits for `Foo` in **file2.rs**, and I write
   `fn my_func(foo: Foo)...`, what do I have here? Is `Foo` a `struct` or a trait (`impl Foo`) here?

I read the Rust book and manual, but they explain only
explicit usage, not mention what happens with `trait` with the same name (`impl`). The Rust book tells you to import traits explicitly, if so and `Drop` is not imported by `use mod1::Foo`, this is a really, really bad thing.

Comment: [This is some good reading](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In **file2.rs** I wrote `use mod1::Foo;`.
>
> What do I actually have in **file2.rs**? Only `struct Foo`, `impl Foo`? What about `impl Drop for Foo`?

When you `use` a type like a struct or an enum, you get all of the *inherent methods*; those defined in the `impl Foo`. You'd also be able to access any public fields on the type.

> If I get all traits for `Foo` in **file2.rs**, and I write `fn my_func(foo: Foo)`, what do I have here? Is `Foo` a struct or a trait (`impl Foo`) here?

`impl Foo` **is not a trait**. `trait Bar` defines a trait. `impl Bar for Foo`  implements a trait for the type `Foo`. `impl Foo` creates *inherent methods*; these are not related to traits.

> I read the Rust book and manual, but they explain only explicit usage, not mention what happens with trait with the same name (impl). The Rust book tells you to import traits explicitly, if so and `Drop` is not imported by `use mod1::Foo`, this is a really, really bad thing.

That would be a very bad idea for the language designers to have made. Thankfully, they didn't do that. Importing something simply allows the code that imported it to use it. It doesn't cause the code to disappear if it's not imported.

The compiler itself is the user of types that implement `Drop`, so you can think of it as the compiler implementation has `use Drop` in it somewhere. This is probably not *literally* true, but a mental model. Just because your code doesn't import `Drop` doesn't mean some other code couldn't.

As mentioned elsewhere, you don't have to import `Drop` anyway, as it's [included in the prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html).